# Git difference between 2 branches show changes made in feature branch only

Tags: git, git-diff

How can I get git difference of my feature branch w.r.t master branch. I only want changes that are there in the feature branch and exclude changes of master branch.
E.g.If feature branch has following commits:

- b
- c
- e
- f

Whereas master has following commits:

- a
- d
- e
- f

Then I want all directory names that were modified in just the commit b & c (don't need commit hash just the directory names). I have so far tried `git --name-only diff master..feature` command but it seems it is returning all the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@[Mark's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7050130/mark-adelsberger) answer really helped me find what I was looking for, thanks a lot for that. But with local branch names I was also getting a lot of entries including the .gitignore which did not have any changes. What worked for me is following, which is a slight modification of Mark's original answer:

```
git diff --name-only $(git merge-base remotes/origin/master remotes/origin/feature) remotes/origin/feature
```

This gave me exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The first way that comes to mind is

```
git diff --name-only $(git merge-base master feature) feature
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on create `Pull Request` in `git hub/bitbucket` or whatever you are using. Base branch should be `master`. You can see the changes. Include/exclude the changes in feature branch and then merge it in `master`.

Comment: I know that we can achieve this on UI by raising pull request but I need a command so that I can obtain the name of the folders modified. Based on this there is some further requirement that I know how to handle.